# Adobesign PHP API v6 doesn't set location for custom fields

Tags: php

I tried to follow this guide: https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/kb/formfields-option-is-not-available-in-v6-of-rest-api-adobe-sign.html

to put some fields in my pdf document.

If I set AUTHORING like the tutorial, i get error when I try to change the state.

So I tried using DRAFT mode

```
$fields_array = array(
    "fileInfos" => array([
        "transientDocumentId" => $transientDocumentId
    ]),
    "name" => "test",
    "participantSetsInfo" => array([
        "memberInfos" => array([
            "email" => "myemail@email.com"
        ]),
        "order" => 1,
        "role" => "SIGNER"
    ]),
    "mergeFieldInfo" => array([
          "defaultValue" => "Test",
          "fieldName" => "sigBlock2"
    ]),
    "signatureType" => "ESIGN",
    "state" => "DRAFT" // per assegnare poi le coordinate, usare AUTHORING
);


$postdata = json_encode($fields_array);

$resource = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($resource, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.eu1.echosign.com/api/rest/v6/agreements",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
));

$res = curl_exec($resource);

if ($res === false) {
    throw new Exception(curl_error($resource), curl_errno($resource));
}

$result = json_decode($res,true);

curl_close($resource);

$id = $result['id'];
```

Then set custom fields like tutorial

```
$header =array(
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token, 
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json"
);

$fields_array = array(
    "fields" => [array(
        "locations" => [array(
            "height" => 36,
            "left" => 75,
            "pageNumber" => 2,
            "top" => 200,
            "width" => 150
        )]
        ,
        "contentType" => "SIGNER_COMPANY",
        "name" => "sigBlock1",
        "backgroundColor" => "#CCCCCC",
        "inputType" => "TEXT_FIELD",
        "required" => true,
        "visible" => true
    )]

);

$postdata = json_encode($fields_array);

var_dump($postdata);

$resource = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($resource, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.eu1.echosign.com/api/rest/v6/agreements/" . $id . "/formFields",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
));

$res = curl_exec($resource);
```

But without success. I get no errors. If I try to get update info about document I see custom field in response but....if I try to open link to PDF to sign...i don't see the fields inside the PDF.

Any suggest?

Comment: It's happening the same for me... Did you get any solution?

Comment: @Tygreton yes... i have changed provider! never received info from ADOBE...

Answer (score 1):

1. set agreement state to AUTHORING
2. do a `GET /agreements/$id/members`
3. use the **id** of your participant in the **assignee** field of your form field
4. do your `PUT agreements/$id/formFields`

example

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "locations": [
                {
                    "pageNumber": 1,
                    "width": 150,
                    "height": 50,
                    "left": 75,
                    "top": 200
                }
            ],
            "assignee": "{{participant_id}}",
            "inputType": "SIGNATURE",
            "contentType": "SIGNATURE",
            "name": "Sign Here!",
            "recipientIndex": 2,
            "required": 1,
            "visible": true
        }
    ]
}
```